# WebStorm for NodeJS add NPM modules in 'External Libraries'

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

Is there a way to add the NPM NodeJS External modules so my node project modules appear in 'External Libraries' and are resolved by code completion and navigate?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the corresponding modules installed locally (in the project folder) or just globally? In any case, you can add a new library in Settings/javaScript/Libraries and select your node_modules folder (press '+' and choose 'attach directories') - the corresponding files will appear as External libraries. Note that since WebStorm 7 the IDE prompts you to create a library out of your node_modules located in the project folder; and you can use npm integration toi instrall missing packages

Comment: I add the mode_modules folder ,but it not work. I set NODE_PATH as my mode_modules folder,it's ok. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

on webstorm go to:

- file
- settings
- javascript
- libraries
- download or add

Comment: This method works in 2023.  Webstorm doesn't detect the libs automatically with "npm install".  "Download or add" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, besides enabling code completion in `Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)` > `Languages and Frameworks` > `Node.js` after downloading it via the `Settings` > `Plugins` section, You have to actually install the Node.js kind of manually.

First, create a basic `package.json` file containing all the config info needed to install Node.js,
for more info look here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-json-guide

After you've done that, simply open up the terminal emulator (`Alt + f12`) and type in `npm install`.

As long as you have the `package.json` file in the same directory, everything should work fine, 
and your IDE - webstorm in this case, should add Node's external modules automatically,
to the `External libraries` > `Node.js core` section in your project tab.

Cheers.