# Cannot find module 'sails'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, global, webstorm

I am trying to run a sails application with Webstorm 7.0.3.
this appear when i try to run the server in the console log:

---

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sails'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (C:\Users****\projects\WebstormProjects****\app.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)

Process finished with exit code 8

---

i installed sails globaly. i know that this is dont work because it cant find the sails module in the project's local 'node_modules' directory. if ill install again 'sails' localy it will work. but i dont want to...

Is there a way to make it work with sails global install? thanks!

Comment: You may have installed sails globally, but you still need to start the project from within the project folder. cd out of your project folder and use sails -v to make sure you have access to it. If not, check your PATH

Comment: out of the project directory sails command works.

Comment: sails command work everywhere (in terminal), because it installed globaly. but from some reason when i hit the run button in webstorm it cant find the the sails module. he takes only the modules installed localy in the project directory. what should i do to make it look in addition on the global modules ...?

Comment: Can you modify the run/build config in webstorm? I'm not too familiar with that IDE. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759055/webstorm-for-nodejs-add-npm-modules-in-external-libraries

Answer (score 1):

The `sails` module that your code is looking for is not the same thing as the `sails` command you're executing at the terminal.

The command generates project skeletons. The module is the code that actually makes it run.

You need to install the command globally and the module locally.

Global installation (using `npm install -g`) does *not* make modules available globally to all node applications, it's only there for command line stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If your applications relies on Sails, you should have it in your dependencies in `package.json` as well as installed locally.

If you don't like the way that npm creates a copy of each module locally, use `yarn` and tell it to symlink the cached version.